# Joining lines intersecting with only one other line?

Tags: qgis, python, intersection, attribute-joins

I have road centerline file that is split into smaller segments. I need to make a node file. How can I join line segments intersecting only once - so I wouldn't join ones that have 3-4 intersections like those circled in last picture?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: They are called "pseudo nodes" and the GRASS tool ´v.build.polylines´ should do the job for you.